# Visual feedback (color transition) on TextField?

Tags: qml, transition

I have an app with numerous numbers in text fields (in a GridLayout) and would like to visually highlight fields which get changed (something like color changing from the original to red and then back, so something similar).

I am new to animations/transitions and so on, so I would like to ask about what is the correct approach to this.

I was looking at tutorials in Qt Creator but they attach transitions to elements in the QML code already, whereas I would like to get the element by its id and say, now run the highlight transition, without adding something to its code. Is that possible?

Comment: Showing a minimal example of what you have so far and the exact effect you want (i.e. no "something like" but rather "this specific effect, which can only be applied to one control at a time/can be applied to many controls at the same time") will help get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own control, derived from `Text` and add inside all the animation logic you want.
For example:

**MyItem.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12

Text {
    id: txt
    property bool hightlight: false
    property color textColor: color
    property color hightlightColor: "red"
    onHightlightChanged: {
        if(hightlight)
            anim.running = true;
    }

    SequentialAnimation
    {
        id: anim
        running: false
        PropertyAnimation {
            target: txt
            property: "color"
            to: hightlightColor
            duration: 500
        }
        PropertyAnimation {
            target: txt
            property: "color"
            to: textColor
            duration: 500
        }
        ScriptAction {
            script: txt.hightlight = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Test"
    visible: true
    height: 250
    width: 200

    MyItem {
        id: item
        text: "Hello"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        hightlightColor: "red"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                item.hightlight = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```